# Working Linq Query but slow performance

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have this linq query that queries a table that retains any change history done to any of the tables is constructed like this:

```
History (Primary Key) | Table_Name | Primary_Key | Field_Name | Old_Value | New_Value | Action_Type | Action_Date | Action_User
```

The linq query I have that queries this table is this:

```
 var complaintHistory = from histories in DbContext.Histories
                                       where ((from c in taskIds
                                               select "<Task_ID=" + c + ">").Contains(histories.Primary_Key) ||
                                              (from c in notificationListIds
                                               select "<Notification_List_ID=" + c + ">").Contains(histories.Primary_Key) ||
                                              (from c in emailSentIds
                                               select "<Email_Sent_ID=" + c + ">").Contains(histories.Primary_Key) ||
                                                  histories.Primary_Key == "<Complaint_ID=" + Complaint.Complaint_ID + ">") &&
                                                  histories.Field_Name != "rowversion"
                                       select histories;
```

I'm having serious latency whenever I call this query. Can this linq query be re-written to increase performance dramatically or am I trying to go up a creek without a paddle?

Comment: This would be a good question for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Oh? was this the improper SO for this question?

Comment: I'm a little confused because there are other questions about LINQ query optimizations.

Comment: The improper SE, yes. If your code works, put it up at CR and mention you're specifically looking for performance improvements.

Comment: There is NOTHING wrong with posting this question on StackOverflow...however the suggestion to also place it on CodeReview is a good suggestions.

Comment: Why do you use these strings like "<Task_ID=" + c + ">"? And how many elements does `taskIds` contain typically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Always first look at the generated SQL when performance is bad. You'll see that it's horrible. It contains numerous `UNION`s of single row tables by which the strings `from c in taskIds select "<Task_ID=" + c + ">"` etc. are built.

Keep in mind that the whole query is translated into SQL. If you'd only have...

```
where taskIds.Contains(histories.Primary_Key)
```

...etc., then these predicates could have been translated into `IN` statements. In your query, the composed strings `"<Task_ID=" + c + ">"` must be built in clunky SQL. This is enough to pull down the query optimizer. Also, the number of elements in `taskIds` greatly influences performance and it doesn't take many elements (~50) to touch the maximum nesting level.

First thing to try is to relieve the database engine from building these composed strings by doing this yourself first:

```
var task_Ids = (from c in taskIds
               select "<Task_ID=" + c + ">").ToArray();
```

And

```
where task_Ids.Contains(histories.Primary_Key)
```

Same for the other two ID lists.

If `taskIds` doesn't contain too many elements (not *thousands*) you can also build one list containing the three string compositions:

```
var ids = (from c in taskIds select "<Task_ID=" + c + ">")
               .Union(
               (from c in taskIds select "<Notification_List_ID="" + c + ">"))
               .Union(
               (from c in taskIds select "<Email_Sent_ID=" + c + ">"))
               .ToArray();
```

and use only one `Contains` statement.

More fundamentally, I think you shouldn't store primary keys in this form. It mixes data and a specific presentation implementation (which in itself is evil enough) and it needlessly complicates querying. It would have been much easier if `Primary_Key` would have been a simple value, equal to the originating record, probably in a composite key with a type field that determines `Task`, `Notification`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

as folks have mentioned, CR can give you thorough comments on performance. but here is a first poke at it.

from your linq query, it looks like a straight-forward check like this:

*'give me all history records, where field name is not 'rowversion' and primary key is either (complaint id or in the list of email sent ids, notification ids or task ids)'*

from a linq-to-sql perspective, the 'contains' clause is the only tricky part, but LInq-to-sql is smart enough to translate it into the SQL IN clause with the values.

so the final SQL query should be doing 3 IN checks. shouldn't be a problem for SQL.

and as long as the **Primary_key** column is indexed (from the name, i am assuming it is, since a primary key is cluster-indexed) and possibly the 'Field_name' column, the query looks fine.

try capturing the query in SQL Profiler, and run it in SQL management studio and look at the Execution plan.